# Android sync without login

Tags: android, synchronization

I'm trying to add a synchronization function to my app which will work like this :

I want it to be login free, so no new account will be needed. 
The data will be assigned to the user's google account on which he's logged in.
On server side, there will be a mySQL database wich will hold the user's data.

I didn't find a useful tutorial. http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/AndroidSyncApp This one uses some weird servlet or whatever, and the official google tut is very briefly explained.

Could anyone help me ?

I could imagine synchronization through xml - like implementing a function that would create an xml file from my database, upload it to the server and parse it/put it my online database.

This would be useful, if I only wanted to be able to modify data on one end - the phone - but then it wouldn't be called syncing, rather backup.

Or maybe I could request a similar xml file from the server. I think it should be possible to send some kind of query from the device to the server which would call a function that creates an xml file from database entries and then download the created file, parse it, compare with the device's database and update the database if some file was updated (it's 'last edited' time was changed).

So on each sync cycle I would first get the server-side xml file, update the local DB, then create the xml file from local DB, send it to the server and update the online DB. Only files with newer "last edited" time would be updated.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the communication between App and Server, you could use XML or JSON. But if you also want to write to the Database and/or transfer files to/from the Server, you're going to need something with Sockets.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

In my case I have two separate parts to the app, one is a genreal information feed, the other is secured user data.

I need them both to sync, but the general feed needs to sync even if the user has not logged in.

There are two things I'm going to try:

1) Add the sync but don't ask the AccountManager for the token. This might skip the whole login prompt.

2) USe a separate service that can wake up and sync the general data. (I suspect this is the correct way to go).